# Why I am getting segmentation fault error while converting video using FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, segmentation-fault

I am converting each type video to .flv video using FFmpeg but for some videos I got

"Segmentation fault" error why this error was occurred?

my code to convert .flv file is

function convert_flv($vidtime,$infile, $outfile, $w = 0, $h = 0, $extra_infile = '', $extra_outfile = '') { 
    $parms = '';
    if($w == 0 && $h == 0) {
        //$parms .= '-sameq ';
    } else {
        $parms = '-s {$w}x{$h} ';
    }

```
if($vidtime==60)
{
    $cmd = ffmpeg($infile, $outfile, $parms.' '.$extra_infile, '-t 00:01:00 -ar 22050 -r 15 -f flv  '.$extra_outfile);

}
else
{
    $cmd = ffmpeg($infile, $outfile, $parms.' '.$extra_infile, '-t 00:04:00 -ar 22050 -r 15 -f flv  '.$extra_outfile);
}

print_r($cmd);
return $cmd;
```

}

and I am trying to convert .mp4 file.

Comment: Please elaborate. What are the parameters you are passing to ffmpeg, type of original videos etc...

Comment: my function for convert to .flv is
function convert_flv($vidtime,$infile, $outfile, $w = 0, $h = 0, $extra_infile = '', $extra_outfile = '') { 
 $parms = '';
 if($w == 0 && $h == 0) {
  //$parms .= '-sameq ';
 } else {
  $parms = '-s {$w}x{$h} ';
 }
 
 if($vidtime==60)
 {
  $cmd = ffmpeg($infile, $outfile, $parms.' '.$extra_infile, '-t 00:01:00 -ar 22050 -r 15 -f flv  '.$extra_outfile);
  
 }
 else
 {
  $cmd = ffmpeg($infile, $outfile, $parms.' '.$extra_infile, '-t 00:04:00 -ar 22050 -r 15 -f flv  '.$extra_outfile);
 }
 
 print_r($cmd);
 return $cmd;
}
and I am trying to convert .mp4 file.